# "ReferenceError: document is not defined" while using WebStorm

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am using WebStorm IDE and I'm writing a simple test for my HTML and JS. Here's the code:

JavaScript (index.js):

```
const cool = document.getElementByClassName('error');

cool.innerText = 'test';
```

HTML (index.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src = "index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="theWhat">The DOM</h1>
    <p>Hello World</p>
    <p class="error">Error!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The JavaScript does nothing to any of the 'p' tags and when I run it in it of itself, I et this error:

const pars = document.querySelectorAll('p');
^
ReferenceError: document is not defined
at Object. (C:\Users\sethz\WebstormProjects\jscourse\chapter2\index.js:124:14)

←[90m    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)←[39m

←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)←[39m

←[90m    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)←[39m

←[90m    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)←[39m

←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint as runMain←[39m

←[90m    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47←[39m

Process finished with exit code 1

Ive read it has to do with the interpreter, but I have no idea how to fix that.

**NOTE:**

I'm using Node.js.
I've nevr had this problem before until I deleted it in order to update to the most recent WebStorm (2021)

Comment: apart from that error - the code is wrong anyway .. .since `pars` is a NodeList (an Array like object) - so, trying to use it as if it were an Element won't work

Comment: Are you running this javascript code on node js?

Comment: @bravo I changed it to 'cool' instead and it still didn't work

Comment: @Prana I believe so, i downloaded Node.js and put it in my desktop then created a PATH to it for the interpreter

Comment: @ssethzz document object is works on browser javascript. Node js run time environment is different from browser javascript.

Comment: @ssethzz - wha? well, I guess now `cool` is a NodeList ... the name of the variable doesn't matter, the content is the problem -anyway, that isn't your issue, your issue is you're apparently trying to *execute* a web page using nodejs - I think you need to step back and realise that a webpage is displayed on a browser - and that your "code" is HTML (with a script in it), not javascript (

Comment: You have multiple issues, First: `<script src = index.js></script>` is missing qouts, it should become: `<script src="index.js"></script>` add to that your javascript is being executed before the dom is loaded, and when using `document.querySelectorAll()` it'll return a `NodeList` which you need to loop through its elements to change them one by one:
`const pars = document.querySelectorAll('p'); pars.forEach(el => el.innerHTML = "test");`

Comment: @Prana Gottcha, so how would I go about making a browser javascript?

Comment: @AbdElbeltaji I see what you mean, I changed it to ```const cool = document.getElementByClassName('error');``` instead, then I replaced the second line of code with ```cool.innerText = 'test';``` and it still isn't working. I also fixed the quotes in the script tag

Comment: @ssethzz For that you need to do some steps. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

To include a javascript file to a html page you need to declare static directory
in your index.js/ app.js.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static('public')) // static file
app.listen(8000, console.log(`Server started on port 8000`))
```

We declared 'public' folder in root as static file folder. Then if you have a public/index.js (For browser) in public folder, add it to your html page as usual

```
<script src="/index.js"></script>
```

**Note** that, you don't need to specify the public folder when using the static file in browser.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate all the help guys. I've used some answers and some worked. I have found another way to do this without the extra code as well. I went to the website http://vanilla-js.com/ which downloads a script file that includes DOM manipulation. All I have to do is refractor it and change its name to my liking in my IDE (WebStorm).